# File count of source always shows one more file than destination after duplication

Tags: macos, file-io, applescript

I am working on a simple AppleScript to duplicate an SD card for backup onto my local disk. The duplication and renaming of the folders seems to be going fine and when I spot check everything it seems to be good, but I am also trying to create a little integrity check within the script to make sure everything copied over correctly, but it always returns one more file on the source then ends up in the destination folder.

Everything appears to copy correctly from what I can tell, but why do these file counts differ?

```
global master_folder, final_destination
set the master_folder to "Macintosh HD:Users:jeremy:Desktop:Test Media Folder:"

set the source_folder to (choose folder with prompt "Select the folder that will contain the files to copy:")
set the dayOfSession to (choose from list {"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"} with prompt "Day of Session:") as text
set the timeOfSession to (choose from list {"Morning", "Afternoon", "Night", "Other"} with prompt "Session") as text
set the camera to (choose from list {"100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700"} with prompt "Day of Session:") as text
set the final_destination to my determine_Foldername(dayOfSession, timeOfSession, camera)

tell application "Finder"
    set destination to duplicate source_folder to master_folder
    set name of destination to final_destination
end tell

my check_integrity(source_folder, master_folder & final_destination)

on check_integrity(source, destination)
    set warnings to 0

    set numberOfSourceFiles to my file_count(source)
    set numberOfDestinationFiles to my file_count(destination)

    if not (numberOfSourceFiles = numberOfDestinationFiles) then
        set warnings to warnings + 1
        display dialog "It does not appear that all the files copied over." with title "UH-OH!"
    end if

    if warnings = 0 then
        display dialog "Everything seems to have gone as planned." with title "All done!"
    end if
end check_integrity

on file_count(theFolder)
    return (do shell script "find " & quoted form of POSIX path of theFolder & " \\! -name '.*' | wc -l") as integer
end file_count

on determine_Foldername(day, time, camera)
    if (day = "Thursday") then
        set day to "0828"
    else if (day = "Friday") then
        set day to "0829"
    else if (day = "Saturday") then
        set day to "0830"
    else if (day = "Sunday") then
        set day to "0831"
    end if

    if (time = "Morning") then
        set time to "0900"
    else if (time = "Afternoon") then
        set time to "1300"
    else if (time = "Night") then
        set time to "1830"
    else if (time = "Other") then
        set time to "2400"
    end if

    set the card to 1
    repeat
        set folder_name to "DT-" & day & "-" & time & "." & (camera + card)
        tell application "Finder"
            if not (exists master_folder & folder_name) then
                exit repeat
            end if
        end tell
        set the card to card + 1
    end repeat

    return folder_name
end determine_Foldername
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I am duplicating over a whole drive, there was a `.Trashes` folder that `find` was counting but `duplicate` wasn't sending over. I decided to just do my count on all files/folders that don't start with a period. So my file counter now looks like this...

```
on file_count(theFolder)
    return (do shell script "find " & quoted form of POSIX path of theFolder & " \\( ! -regex '.*/\\..*' \\) | wc -l") as integer
end file_count
```